GeckoView on Android - support for offline "PWA"
I integrate a GeckoView into an Android app and the GeckoView loads a PWA (a website that has a service worker that enables the website to be loaded offline using a web Cache API).
It works ok in Chrome & Firefox and when there is not internet, it uses the Cache API to serve the HTML (and other resources) from the cache.
The problem is that it does not work inside of the GeckoView, it just shows a blank page without any error message etc. (I don't see any relevant errors in the adb, and the console output is enabled).
Is there some way how to debug this? I run the Android app in Android Emulator and for some reason, Firefox can not connect to it even if the remote debugging is enabled (I can not see it in the connected devices).
The GeckoView version: 93.0.20210902092450 (nightly)
Thank you in advance for any help!

Update #1: the offline support does not also work in Firefox 93, so I will investigate...
Update #2: after few refreshes, it starts working in both GeckoView 93 and Firefox 93, so it seems that the browser caches some file that enables it to work offline (which is the service worker does not "pre cache" by default). Maybe some polyfill or something is missing.
Update #3: it seems that Firefox is waiting for some requests to timeout and then it "shows" the webpage. So I will just cache all the stuff that Firefox is trying to load from the internet and it will probably solve this issue. If someone has an idea in which version this behaviour was changed in Firefox, please leave a reply.
